# NoReverseMatch at / Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['posts/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']

Tags: python, django

I'm building a django blog app. But, when I'm trying to build detail pages for blog posts, I'm getting this error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['posts/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']
```

This is my `post_detail` view function:

```
def post_detail(request,post_id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=post_id)

    return render(request, 'blog/detail.html',{'post':post})
```

My url route:

```
path('posts/<int:post_id>/',views.post_detail,name='detail'),
```

And the line that links to detail page:

```
<p class="lead my-3"><a href="{% url 'blog:detail' post.id %}" class="text-white font-weight-bold">{{ latest_post.title }}</a></p>
```

I don't think I should have any error in this. Where am I going wrong?

***EDIT***

I solved this problem. It's just that when I was trying to add this "detail" link to the "latest_post" variable. But I had specified it only for "post" variable. I just replaced it with "post" and it worked!

Comment: What is the URL you are trying to access?

Comment: It's my url that I have specefied in the question. The one with the name "detail"

Comment: I mean on the browser, what is the complete address you enter there?

Comment: Oh that. Its "localhost:8000/posts/1/". That 1 in the url differs according to the id.

Comment: And one more thing. When I manually go to "localhost:8000/posts/1/", I don't get any error and see the expected output. But, when I try to add a link to that page, I see the "NoReverseMatch" error.

Comment: Do you have  `app_name = 'blog'` in your urls.py? Otherwise, can you try to update url from blog:detail to only detail in your template?

Comment: Yes I have specified the 'app_name = 'blog' ' in my urls.py.

Comment: You have `latest_post` and `post` in the template. Are you sure you have access to the post in the template? The error is telling you that you are that you are passing an empty argument to the URL. This means `post.id` is empty.

Comment: I have solved this problem and edited my question accordingly.